# My condenser dryer is steaming up my kitchen and utility room

Tags: condensation

An engineer  fitted  a new pump to my AEG Lavatherm condenser dryer. It still has not solved the problem of a very hot steamy kitchen, when I'm drying my clothes.

Comment: Welcome! Posting model number might help us help you.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Hot, wet air from the dryer should go through a heat exchanger with room air, which causes it to condense.   Maybe the heat exchanger is leaking/broken, but I would have thought the engineer wouldd have chcked that. Really, condensing dryers are not a great system, heat pump dryers are what they're meant to be.

Answer (score 2):

Although we haven't had any problems with similar dryers, it would appear that others do.  I wouldn't call AEG a cheap brand so I would suspect that the engineer has not fixed it properly.

> Condenser tumble dryers don’t use a vent hose, and should turn all the steam into water. But because they create heat when running, a condenser dryer will heat the air around it and the moisture in the air will condense on any cold surface such as tiles or even other appliances near by – especially if used in a garage near a freezer as mine is.
>
> If it’s not a high quality dryer it may also allow some moist air from the drying process into the room too. The only answer is to create more ventilation or make the room warmer.
>
> We have a condenser dryer installed in our garage and even though it doesn’t need venting, we always have to open the garage door a little in cold weather to prevent condensation collecting on the freezer doors.

From [Condenser Tumble Dryer Causes Condensation](https://www.whitegoodshelp.co.uk/condenser-tumble-drier-causes-condensation/)

We have Miele appliances as below and have no issues.  In the previous house, we had AEG appliances in a slightly larger laundry, again with no issues.  They are tiled and have stainless rails for coat hangers above the bench.  And we don't get a single drop of condensation.

**Suggestions**

The Meile has warnings for these, perhaps yours do not.

- Empty the water container/tray before every cycle
- Clean the lint from the filters before every cycle.

[image: Our Setup]